# innosetup semicolon expected in code section

Tags: inno-setup

I have an error while compiling the code section of my inno script.

The code section

```
var
  ServerID: String;
  EditServerID: TEdit;
  PageIDServer: TWizardPage;

function getServerID(Param: String): String;
begin
  Result := ServerID.Text; <--- Error here
end;
```

And the procedure section:

```
if InstallService(ExpandConstant('"{app}\Client.exe -{code:GetServerID}" Client'),'Client','Client','Client',SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS,SERVICE_AUTO_START) = true then
begin
  StartService('Client');
  Sleep(500);
end
else
  MsgBox('Client service could not be installed',mbInformation, MB_OK);
```

I read that this error may be linked to the `{code:}` but don't know why.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I can't see any problem in this code. Maybe you're passing invalid number of parameters into your `InstallService` function. Hard to tell without knowing the whole code. Here's a [`simple proof`](http://pastebin.com/LkcYehjr).

Comment: Is serverid a built in object? i dont see a definition for it in that scope nor does the innosetup documentation refer to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were trying to access a `Text` property of a string variable `ServerID`, but you certainly wanted to get that value from the `EditServerID` edit box. If that is so, write it this way:

```
function GetServerID(Param: string): string;
begin
  Result := EditServerID.Text;
end;
```

The same applies for the code in your `NextButtonClick` event method. Btw. the `ServerID` variable seems to be unused in your script, you're just assigning its value to the `EditServerID.Text` property when the edit box is created, but at that time the variable is empty, so I think you can just remove it from your script to not mislead you anymore.